# Pymongo get random record and element of the record

Tags: python, mongodb, random, pymongo

I have a record like this in my MongoDB

```
{
_id: "611ae422a01534cecce5533d"
firstname:"Test1"
lastname: "Test2"
}
```

This is my code

```
res = firstnameCollection.aggregate([{'$sample': {'size': 1 }}])
print(list(res))
```

I want to get a random record out of my database. I have many records like I mentioned above.
The output I get is a list of the record. When I remove the list attribute, I get:

```
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x0000021078B82EB0>
```

I just want to output the firstname of the element:

```
Test1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you convert the response to a list, you can retrieve the first element using an index. You could do something like this:

```
docs = list(res)
first_name = docs[0]['firstname'] if docs and 'firstname' in docs[0] else 'placeholder'
```

The approach makes sure you don't get an `IndexError` by taking advantage of the fact that empty lists are [considered false](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). It also checks that [`firstname` is in the document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) so that you don't get a `KeyError`.